# Torque calculation for a robot

Tags: motors, design, robotics

if I have a robot 50kg, 6 wheels and i want to move it inside a sewer pipe what is the torque required?
and there is any DC motor model can satisfy this function?

Comment: This is not enough info. It gets asked a lot, but very few get satisfactory answers. Firstof we would need to know the reduced inertia and all friction losses of your robot. Second, once you know the friction losses you suddenly realize that as long as you overcome those the robot will accelerate, but slowly. Then it becomes a question of desired acceleration. Its often easier just to estimate energy/work requirements instead of delving into all of this. and then just add a bit to lot extra.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do the math in the question you originally posed this question in. It's no different: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31501/how-can-i-calculate-the-power-and-torque-required-for-the-motor-on-a-wheeled-rob As it stands, it seems like you just want someone to do your work for you.